# Fill level calculation of a tank via SQLite

Tags: java, sql, excel, sqlite

I am still struggling with my simulation project. Part of it is to determine fill levels of different tanks. The simulation output is written into a SQLite database.

The output-stream contains this information:

1. volume of the input in tank (volume)
2. temperature of the input volume (temperature)
3. starting time of the input flow (start_time)
4. ending time of the input flow (end_time)
5. flow rate of the input flow (flow_rate)

An example SQLite database:

[SQLite - SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/c9ab1/1)

With these few lines I would like to create a SQL view over the whole timespan. Starting with time=1, 2, 3, .... 40. Where the fill level could be directly plotted and also the temperature is calculated accordingly.
I actually have done this with an Excel spreadsheets, hope you can see it:

[Excel spreadsheet - Editgrid](http://www.editgrid.com/user/stefanhubert/fill_level)

For calculating the temperature_flowrate of mixtures I have used this equation:

T_flowrate = ((flowrate_1 * temp_flowrate_1)+((flowrate_2 * temp_flowrate_2)))/(flowrate_1 + flowrate_2)

**How is it possible to do this view (see spreadsheet A1:E44) with the provided SQLite database?**

(Hopefully I was able to provide all the information needed)

Comment: Do you really need to implement this only in SQL?

Comment: Actually I thought this might be the fastest and cleanest option. The 'simulation-engine' is written in Java, so doing it with Java also is an option. I am very open minded. But the downside is that we do not only have four lines of 'output-stream' (like in the given example) from the simulation, but 1000's of it.